# Unable to create an accurate xpath to locate an item

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I'am stuck creating an appropriate `xpath` to locate the `Title:` and `Genre:` from the below elements.

Html elements:

```
<div class="mdif">
    <ul>
        <li><b>Title:</b>Army Of Darkness</li> 
        <li><b>Genre:</b></li> Horror
    </ul>
</div>
```

Output I would like to have:

```
Army Of Darkness
Horror
```

I've tried with the below one to get `Army Of Darkness` and I got success. I don't know whether it is the most accurate one:

```
root.xpath("//div[@class='mdif']//li/text()")[0]
```

However, in case of getting `Horror`, I get stuck. Any help to get `Horror`as result using xpath from the above elements will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `<li><b>Genre:</b></li> Horror` invalid DOM structure.

Comment: Whatever it is, I can locate it using `css selector`. So, I thought it would be possible to do using `xpath` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below XPath and let me know in case of any issues:

```
//div[@class='mdif']//ul//text()[normalize-space() and not(parent::b)]
```

`normalize-space()` predicate should discard text node that consists of space characters only and `not(parent::b)` predicate should allow you to ignore `"Title:"` and `"Genre:"` nodes

Comment: Awesome sir. This is it. Btw, the other one i defined within my post to get `Army of Darkness`, is that okay?

Comment: `//div[@class='mdif']//li/text()` this one? Yes, for Title it's ok